# Data Quality Services in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, data-quality-services

Do you know anything about Data Quality Services? When it will be introduced in Microsoft Azure? Or maybe there is some services with same functions and possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want Data Quality Services (DQS) there is nothing to stop you provisioning some virtual machines (VMs) and installing SQL Server and DQS on them, ie as Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS).  See here for DQS installation instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/data-quality-services/install-windows/install-data-quality-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks Bob, it's some option too.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/17695042-dqs-data-quality-services) there are a good amount of people interested on that feature to come to SQL Azure but there is no official response. Please vote on that URL to grab attention from the Azure SQL Database team about that topic.

Meanwhile you can install SQL Server and DQS on an Azure VMm but you may also consider third-party products available on Azure Marketplace ([here](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?search=Data%20Quality&page=1)).